# Showing blank when I use external link in anchor tag and redirect in AWS for specific path

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, path

In my react app I use an anchor tag and use an external link to redirect.

Simply Like this

```
<a className="nav-a" href="http://www.example.com/blog" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" >Blog</a>
```

In AWS, I redirect or apply the policy to it such as when the path is like `www.example.com/blog` then the main URL load of `http://blog.example.com/` and in URL section we should see `www.example.com/blog`

But actually, It does not work in only the chrome browser.

Working fine in all browsers except chrome

Suggest me a solution for it

Comment: Your entire website is `http`, not `https`? chrome is very strict about not mixing `http` and `https`.

Comment: @Marcin then what should I use actually? HTTP or HTTPS in this URL ```http://blog.example.com/``` which is assign in aws?

Comment: If your blog supports https, then https. Have you checked chrome console for any error messages?

Comment: @Marcin In console showing this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Comment: seems its wrong address.

Comment: @Marcin but when I hard refresh browser then only it appears fine. Otherwise, this error showing